# How many times can I install an application I've purchased on the Market?

Tags: google-play-store

I have just bought an HTC HD2 and I immediately installed a custom Android ROM. I will probably change ROMs often.

If I buy an application from the Android Market how many times can I download and install it?

Answer (score 8):

As long as you are using the same Google account, you should be able to download it as many times as you need to.  The Android Market keeps track of who has bought which applications and allows them to be re-downloaded.

Comment: Is that "should" that worries me. I do not want to risk that Google decides to block me from downloading applications that I bought.

Comment: @ Drake, Why do you have that concern? Did you read something where this has happened? Or did you read anywhere that Google has limits? As far as I know they could care less how many times you download. But keep in mind to download you need to have uninstalled the app first, or wiped your phone. So another questions might be why all the uninstalling and reinstalling of the same app? Unless you are rooting, in which case there is still no concern there. Google's marketplace is open and they have given no indication to change.

Comment: Can you share apps across the same account on different phones? e.g. my wife and I share a google account for app purchases so can we install the app on both of our phones?

Comment: @goap I think so, but I haven't tried it.  You can certainly transfer your apps to a new handset so I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @GusPaul: Yes, you can share apps across different android devices so long as the primary account used to set up the device is the same.  I do this across two phones and a tablet myself.