# What will happen to my apps when i switch phones?

Tags: paid-apps

When I get a new android I would to keep the apps I have purchased. I will keep the same account but I was wondering if I will have to rebuy my games?

Comment: Please see [How many times can I install an application I've purchased on the Market?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/982/16575) / [If I flash my ROM or wipe my device after buying an app, will I have to buy it again?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15828/16575)

Answer (score 2):

No.  Android apps (as well as anything else (books, magazines, movies, etc.) sold in the Play Store) are linked to your google account, not to your physical device.

All the apps and games you previously purchased will be available for download.